# WP7 how to accelerate animation

Tags: windows-phone-7, animation, storyboard, panel

I'm using `Storyboard` with `DoubleAnimation` to translate Y of a `StackPanel` from top to bottom.

It works fine. But what I want is to **accelerate** it when it is about to reach bottom (like the status panel of Android).

I read this tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746613.aspx), but it seems to apply to Silverlight only.

How to do that ?

Comment: @CarlSaldanha I want to, but some answer does not satify my need. On the other way, doing so will confuse later user who want to find the best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your looking for is an easing class.

Easing classes change speed with time. So an animation will start out slow and go fast or the opposite etc.etc.

Here's the documentation on `ExponentionalEasing`. Its pretty straightforward 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.exponentialease(v=vs.95).aspx

However if you want more fine tuning you'll have to use KeyFrames and set the time difference between them

Comment: ExponentionalEasing with EaseIn works like a charm, thanks :)